# how can ı controll the dom element under the script tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, dom

```
<script> var data = document.getElementByClassName('data'); </script>
<div class="data"> this element should be under the script tags  </div>
```

code style should be same like above codes.
div element is not remove or relocation .
How can ı resolve this issue
Regards

Comment: Put the script tag after the DOM element. When the script runs, the DOM element doesn't exist yet.

Comment: There's also no function named `getElementByClassName`. It's called `getElementsByClassName` (note the plural "Elements"), and it returns a list of all the elements with that class. You'll need to index it or iterate over it.

Comment: actually this element is a extention on chrome. When ı was click anywhere extention is running and dom element is placed under the this tag.

Comment: What does node.js have to do with a Chrome extension?

Comment: And why did you tag it jquery? You've using vanilla JS.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to do with the Chrome extension. You need to post a more complete [mre]